# Iaas vs Paas in context of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, saas, iaas

This is not a duplicate question. I am just confused in Iaas,Saas with respect to AWS services like Dynamo, RDS, RedShift and Kinesis etc. They helps users to create database So, should we categorize them in Iaas or Saas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you understand, **SaaS is Software as a Service**. It's more like an on demand application where you don't have to worry about configurations, accesses, whitelisting etc. For instance, Google Maps (or Google Apps).

IaaS or **Infra as a Service** gives you more flexibility in terms of spawning of nodes and clusters, to deal with security services at IP and Port levels, manage access control and authentication etc. On AWS, you may specify what all private or public IPs will have access to your system, whether you prefer to go with dense storage or dense compute nodes for your warehouse, rotate your log files etc.
A page on [Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) reads -

> When you buy a server, you get CPU, memory, storage, and IOPS, all
>   bundled together. With Amazon RDS, these are split apart so that you
>   can scale them independently.

So, in short... Services like AWS and Azure are mostly now either IaaS or PaaS.

Comment: *"Cloud service providers like AWS started with SaaS and have now moved to IaaS."*  Well, no... they didn't.  AWS started with S3, then SQS, then EC2... and none of these are SaaS.  These are infrastructure.  Some might argue that SQS and/or S3 are on the cusp of "platform," but they are definitely not software.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Removed the conflicting text.